# Can't show more than one map annotation in WatchOS 2.0

Tags: mapkit, watchkit, watchos-2

I've updated recently an apple watch app to watchOS 2 and I'm facing a strange behaviour involving map annotations. In the previous version I drew two annotations with two images without any problem but now I can see the images only when just one annotation is shown. When I try to add two annotations, the most recent added is not showing the image and show the default pin annotation. Is that a bug? I'm shocked nobody seems to comment this issue.

This is my code:

```
            var distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(aLocation!)
            let middleLat = (currentLocation.coordinate.latitude + aLocation!.coordinate.latitude)/2
            let middleLon = (currentLocation.coordinate.longitude + aLocation!.coordinate.longitude)/2
            let middleCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(middleLat, middleLon)
            self.theMap.removeAllAnnotations()
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(middleCoords, distance * 1.6 , distance * 1.3)
            self.theMap.addAnnotation(aLocation!.coordinate, withImageNamed: "aAnnotation", centerOffset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            self.theMap.addAnnotation(currentLocation.coordinate, withImageNamed: "UserAnnotationW", centerOffset: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            self.theMap.setRegion(region)
```

In this case only image for "aAnnotation" is shown and "UserAnnotation" get the default pin. If I swap lines 7 and 8, the user image is shown instead.

Anyone?

Thx

Comment: Yes. From what I remember, maps never appeared on simulator with watchOS 2. Now, at least, the annotations are working as expected. No problem at all testing on real device right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've been told in the apple devs forum that in fact this is a bug. So, nothing to worry about if you are in the same case.

Update: Everything back to normal using the new 2.0 GM released today.